# SQL group by number of days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a datetime column 'ts' ( using Amazon Redshift). How can I group data by  30 days. For example if I have a query like this

```
select count(*) from table where ts > '2016-01-19' and ts < '2016-03-22'
```

How can I group this as following groups without specifying these dates explicitly

```
2016-01-19 to 2016-02-18
2016-02-19 to 2016-03-18
```

I've ignored data from 2016-03-19 onwards as there are not many days to form a month?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ts > '2016-01-19' 
              AND ts < '2016-02-18' THEN '2016-01-19 to 2016-02-18' 
         WHEN ts > '2016-02-19' 
              AND ts < '2016-03-18' THEN '2016-02-19 to 2016-03-18' 
       END, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  ts > '2016-01-19' 
       AND ts < '2016-03-22' 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN ts > '2016-01-19' 
                 AND ts < '2016-02-18' THEN '2016-01-19 to 2016-02-18' 
            WHEN ts > '2016-02-19' 
                 AND ts < '2016-03-18' THEN '2016-02-19 to 2016-03-18' 
          END
```